# How to know if a certain sound frequency is being played out of speakers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, audio, frequency

How would I go about getting the sound data from the speakers and checking to see if a very certain frequency is being played? (like see if the 440Hz frequency is playing)

Would I use pyaudio? I dont know much about audio files or audio data so please give me a full run down of how I would accomplish this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to be more specific. See [ask]. Anyway, what about [Librosa Pitch and tuning APIs](https://librosa.org/doc/main/core.html#pitch-and-tuning)?

Comment: @D.L, You can use the ```[mre]``` shorthand link. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400526/1186624).